# How to perform an operation that requires 2 asynchronous tasks to be completed

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, gdc

I have 2 AFNetoworking operations fetching me data, and i have a method that requires both of them to be completed. I've read on the internet i could have an NSOperationQueue to make 1 operation dependent on another operation finishing. While this seems like a good solution in some cases, it seems like it would be difficult if I have code that isnt suited to be an NSOperation.

For example (for illustration purposes)
1. API call A gets an image A
2. API call B gets another image B
3. the maskImage function masks image B onto A

any insights would be helpful!

Comment: Why do you say your code isn't suited for an NSOperation? Also, aren't you complicating things unnecessarily? Just a couple of flags should suffice, no?

Comment: Why is this not suited to a `NSOperation`? I'd just do a simple `NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation operationWithBlock:^{ ... }];` and then add your dependencies to that operation. This seems precisely like something suited for an `NSOperation` (you certainly don't want to be doing complex image processing on the main queue).

Comment: @Rob NSBlockOperation looks great, didnt know it existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about what sort of code you consider ill-suited for `NSOperation`, but I'm wondering if your reticence to use `NSOperation` stems from a desire to avoid writing your own `NSOperation` subclass. Fortunately, using operation queues is much simpler than that. You can use `NSBlockOperation` or `NSInvocationOperation` to quickly create operations.

I would generally use a `NSBlockOperation`:

```
NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
    // do my image processing
    [self applyMaskToImage];
}];
```

Or you could use a `NSInvocationOperation`:

```
NSOperation *completionOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                        selector:@selector(applyMaskToImage)
                                                                          object:nil];
```

You can then (a) call `addDependency` for each of your two download operations, to make `completionOperation` dependent upon both; and (b) add the `completionOperation` to your own queue.